# How to cast stringify json object into Model class in .net core 2.2?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I am receiving `json` object in `string` format. Now i have my model class like this in `.netcore`

```
public class AgentSessions 
{
    // public BsonObjectId _id {get; set;}
    public string[] socketID {get; set;}
    public string agent_id {get; set;}
    public string nsp {get; set;}

    public string createdDate {get; set;}
    public string nickname {get; set;}
    public string email {get; set;}
    public ExpandoObject rooms {get; set;}

    public int chatCount {get; set;}
    public string type{get; set;}
    public string[] location {get; set;}
    public int visitorCount {get; set;}
            public string role {get; set;}
    public Boolean acceptingChats {get; set;}
    public string state {get; set;}
    public ExpandoObject[]  idlePeriod {get; set;}

    public string image {get; set;}
    public ExpandoObject locationCount{get; set;}

    public ExpandoObject callingState{get; set;}

    public ExpandoObject permissions{get; set;}
    public dynamic groups {get; set;}

    public dynamic teams {get; set;}

    public dynamic  isOwner {get; set;}

    public Boolean updated {get; set;}

    public int concurrentChatLimit{get; set;}
    public ExpandoObject conversationState{get; set;}

    public  string id{get; set;}

    public Boolean inactive{get; set;}

    public string lastTouchedTime{get; set;}
    public DateTime? expiry{get; set;}

    public DateTime endingDate{get; set;}
}
```

Now i have to convert that `json` object(string) into my defined `class` type. How can i do that?

```
   stringify data object that i am receiving 

"session":{"_id":"5e2acd287ce5f349008348f5","socketID":[],"agent_id":"5c41ade033aa87307ca9831f","nsp":"/localhost.com","createdDate":"2020-01-24T10:55:36.293Z","nickname":"Nickname Changing","email":"saad_cuteguy11@hotmail.com","rooms":{},"chatCount":0,"type":"Agents","location":[],"visitorCount":0,"role":"admin","acceptingChats":true,"state":"ACTIVE","idlePeriod":[],"image":"https://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-1-021594099427.s3.amazonaws.com/userUploads%2Fhrm.sbtjapan.com%2Fsaadisheikh9705%40sbtjapan.com%2Fpp%2F1546264191938.jpg","locationCount":{},"callingState":{"socketid":"","state":false,"agent":""},"permissions":{"tickets":{"enabled":true,"canMerge":true,"canCreate":true,"canViewLog":true,"canGroup":true,"allowCC":true,"allowBCC":true,"canView":"all","canAssignAgent":true,"canAssignGroup":true,"canAddNote":true,"canAddTag":true,"canAddTask":true,"canChangeState":true,"canExport":true,"canSetPriority":true,"canSnooze":true,"canAddGroupAdmins":true},"chats":{"enabled":true,"allowEmoji":true,"allowAttachments":true,"allowVoicenotes":true,"allowCalling":true,"allowAddAsFaq":true,"allowChatTransfer":true,"allowTypingStatus":true,"canView":"all","canChat":true},"agents":{"enabled":true,"canCreate":true,"canEdit":true,"canChat":true,"canCall":true,"canViewStats":true,"canChangeOwnPassword":true,"canChangeOthersPassword":true},"settings":{"enabled":true,"automatedResponses":{"enabled":true},"rolesAndPermissions":{"enabled":true,"canView":["admin","supervisor","agent","TEst"],"canAddRole":true,"canModifyOwn":true,"canModifyOther":true,"canDeleteRole":true},"formDesigner":{"enabled":true},"ticketManagement":{"enabled":true},"chatTimeouts":{"enabled":true},"callSettings":{"enabled":true},"contactSettings":{"enabled":true},"chatWindowSettings":{"enabled":true},"chatAssistant":{"enabled":true},"webhooks":{"enabled":true},"integerations":{"enabled":true},"knowledgeBase":{"enabled":true},"widgetMarketing":{"enabled":true}},"dashboard":{"enabled":true},"visitors":{"enabled":true},"analytics":{"enabled":true,"visitors":true,"canView":"all","chats":true,"agents":true,"tickets":true},"crm":{"enabled":true},"chatbot":{"enabled":true},"installation":{"enabled":true},"updatedOn":"2020-01-07T11:50:43.690Z"},"groups":["Congo1"],"teams":[],"isOwner":false,"updated":true,"concurrentChatLimit":2,"conversationState":false,"id":"5e2acd287ce5f349008348f5","inactive":false,"lastTouchedTime":"2020-01-24T10:55:37.344Z","endingDate":"2020-01-24T10:55:56.980Z"}
```

And another question is that what happened if any value will not be there in my `json` object(string format) ?

Comment: `stringify` is how Javascript converts an object to JSON. It has nothing to do with the JSON content itself. What you posted is simply a JSON string that needs to be parsed using eg Json.NET or System.Text.JSON

Comment: I am working in .net core. I am receiving stringify object and i want to parse that stringify object into my defined class. So please give me answer that how can i do that

Comment: And also how can i declare nullable values in my mode class(c#) ?

Comment: There's no such thing as a `stringify object`. What you posted is just a JSON string. You can deserialize it with JSON.NET

Comment: As for nullable values, you already defined them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no. .net core is allowing me to declare nullable field on only type `DateTime`. Whne i try to declare `string` or `dynamic` nullable fields so it doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: Those are already nullable. Unless you want to ask something completely different. Have you *tried* to deserialize the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NewtonsoftJson nuget.

It will looks like:

```
var session = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AgentSessions>(stringThatUReceived);
```

Second: it will be set to default(T) in ur object (not sure)

As comment(I need 50 rep to write comments, lol):
Simply write something like this for value-type variables

```
public int? chatCount { get; set; }
```

Comment: And how can i declare nullable fields in my model class? because some fields are optional

Comment: @FahadHassan add your questions in the *question's* text. Besides, you already defined nullable fields.

Answer (score 0):

since you are on .netcore you can use the new System.Text.Json from microsoft.

```
var session = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AgentSessions>(stringYouRecieved);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

Comment: The title of this request suggests that it is for .NET Core 2.2, in which case the new system.text.json namespace isn't available (it was added in .NET Core 3.0).

Comment: you are right, if net core 3.0 is not an option, you have to stick Newtonsoft